# Register OnClickListener, on a dynamically created layout

Tags: java, android, onclick, listener, onclicklistener

I am trying to register an OnClickListener on a dynamically created layout. Lets say I have 10 elements with different data. For each I want to create a ConstraintLayout and add it to my view. I also need to be able to click on it and go to a specific for that layout view.

I know there are RecyclerViews that do similar job but for that scenario I prefer using custom Layout.

Here is my **ConstraintLayout**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class scope extends ConstraintLayout {

MyApplication myApplication;
public LinearLayout widgetContainer;

public void setContainer(LinearLayout container) {
    widgetContainer = container;
    setControlValues();
}

public View widgetView;

public scope(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public scope(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public scope(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scope_layout, this, true);
    widgetView = view;
}

private void setControlValues() {
  }
 }
```

And here is where I create it:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.*;

public class dashboard_view extends Fragment {
MyApplication myApplication;
View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_view_layout, container,
            false);
    myApplication = ((MyApplication) this.getActivity().getApplication());
    loadScopes();
    return view;
}

public void openScopeSummary() {
    scopeSummary_view changeTo_scopeSummary_view = new scopeSummary_view();
    SwitchFragments switchFor_scopeSummary_view = (SwitchFragments) getActivity();
    switchFor_scopeSummary_view.switchFragments(changeTo_scopeSummary_view);
}

public void loadScopes() {
    LinearLayout scopes_container = view.findViewById(R.id.scopes_container);
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10) {
        scope newScope = new scope(getActivity());
        scopes_container.addView(newScope);
        newScope.setClickable(true);
        newScope.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openScopeSummary();
            }
        });
        newScope.setContainer(scopes_container);
        newScope.myApplication = myApplication;
        count = count + 1;
     }
   }
}
```

I don't seem to be able to register the onClick() listener. There are no errors the application runs, it just doesn't work.
Thanks

Edit
Adding the scope_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.aucoda.QuestCSMLive.scope">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/scope_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scope_wrapperborder_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/indicatiorSec"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cloud"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cloud"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/scopeInfo"
            android:layout_width="415dp"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/indicatiorSec"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scopeName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Stadium Event"
                android:textColor="#FF866AA6"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/scopeLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scopeName">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/locationIcon"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/grey_pin"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/locationLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Wembley Stadium"
                    android:textColor="#FF919191"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/locationIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/additionalScopeInfo"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            android:paddingTop="21dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/scopeInfo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/scopeDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dateIcon"
                    android:layout_width="21dp"
                    android:layout_height="21dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dateLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="21 Apr. 2017"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/dateIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/scopeTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scopeDate">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="21dp"
                    android:layout_height="21dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/clock"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="11:00 am"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/timeIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/scopeSize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scopeTime">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sizeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="21dp"
                    android:layout_height="21dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/storage"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sizeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="3MB"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/sizeIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think you need to user array of Scope..instead of creating object of scope and loosing its reference..

Comment: Yeah it seems more sensible. But how is this going to solve the problem of why the OnClickListener is not working? I am setting it just after I create the object before it is "lost". So it shouldn't matter. Should it ?

Comment: Minor aside comment: it's good practice in Java to start class names with an uppercase letter, for example "Scope". Variable names should be lowercase camel case, for example "scopesContainer".

Comment: Thanks for the note Rasmusob! :) 
Can we keep to the point please? 
Thank you

Comment: I think we need to see scope_layout.xml in order to make progress on the problem. You're also no calling the init() method from the Context arg constructor that you're using to create the views. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yeah good point, I have just included it. Up please ↑↑↑

Comment: I think the problem might be that your views have zero size. You can't (easily) click a zero-size view.

Comment: Okay I think I solved it thanks to @Rasmusob. My scope is wrapped with a ScrollView which I think is not clickable.